# find the data type in List

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a requirement where I need to perform some set of transformations based on the datatype of `List`. Lets say if I get `List[String]` I need to apply some transformations but if I get a `List[Int]` some different transformations need to be applied. I had defined a function which will take `List[Any]` and with match statement I need to check the datatype. I tried to use `isInstanceOf` but it didn't work out.

How can I check the datatype of `List`.

Comment: Post code snippets to show use what you've tried. Long story short, you could do it using simple type templates or even do it monadically with `Cats` or `Scalaz` if you need something more powerful.

Comment: Not without reflection, which is ugly and slow. You'll need to capture the type information either in an [ADT](http://typelevel.org/blog/2014/11/10/why_is_adt_pattern_matching_allowed.html) or [HLists](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#polymorphic-function-values)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your list have same type in all of its elements and using plain Scala you could do something like this:

```
def test(list: List[Any]): List[Any] = {
  if(list.isEmpty) return List()
  list.head match {
    case a: String => list.map(str => str.asInstanceOf[String]+"3")
    case a: Int => list.map(int => int.asInstanceOf[Int]+3)
  }
}
```

It's not the best solution, but i don't see anything else which you could use without different libraries

Here is even weirder solution, which allows you to return exactly same type which you've put to this function, of course you would need have exact same type in every element of list:

```
def test[T](list: List[T]): List[T] = {
  if(list.isEmpty) return List()
  list.head match {
    case a: String => list.map(str => (str.asInstanceOf[String]+"3").asInstanceOf[T])
    case a: Int => list.map(int => (int.asInstanceOf[Int]+3).asInstanceOf[T])
  }
}

test(List("123","123")) // res0: List[String] = List(1233, 1233)
test(List(1,2,3)) // res1: List[Int] = List(4, 5, 6)
```

And again edit, last but not least, you can use TypeTag to avoid type erasure and check list type, like this:

```
def test1[T: TypeTag](list: List[T]): List[T] = typeOf[T] match {
  case t if t =:= typeOf[String] => list.map(str => (str.asInstanceOf[String]+"3").asInstanceOf[T])
  case t if t =:= typeOf[Int] => list.map(int => (int.asInstanceOf[Int]+3).asInstanceOf[T])
  case _ => list
}

test1(List("123", "123", "123")) // Strings so: res0: List[String] = List(1233, 1233, 1233)
test1(List("123","123", 1)) // Oh-oh we have not defined type, so: res1: List[Any] = List(123, 123, 1)
test1(List(1,2,3)) // And here we have res2: List[Int] = List(4, 5, 6)
```

Comment: @ishan No problem, i don't see second part of the problem looking at your question, but i hope you will find answer :)